# optimisation of atmel start code

Tags: bootloader, atmelstudio, samd10

I am a beginner in embedded programming and developing bootloader in SAMD10 using Atmel studio 7, I generate Flash read/write/append programme using atmel start website which is taking space of 0x1500 but available memory is only 0x300 for bootloader so I want to optimise it.Can any one suggest me how to write.

Answer (score 0):

0x0300 bytes = less then 1Kb of code.  It is possible to do a simple bootloader but if yours is too complet it may never fit.

I could help and at least tell you if it COULD fit in there if you post your source code of the features you want in the bootloader.  Short story : If you want anything else then a simple bootloader then it won't fit in such a small space.

You could also use a part of the program memory ( outside of the bootloader memory ) to store a routine or two and call them from the bootloader.  For this you must know what you are doing because reprogramming the program will likely erase these functions if you don't make things right.  If you don't know how to do it, I'm not sure you should try it.  On a commercial device, doing this wrong may brick your device which wouldn't be upgradable with the bootloader anymore.   It CAN be done safely if you know what you're doing, I've done similar things a few times with no problem.

A simpler method if you don't want a part of the bootloader in the program space is to add a feature in the program itself that allows a firmware upgrade.  Just put your bootloader source code in the program and you're done.